# Bulk update children table records set on master table records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have imported 2 tables from excel and I want to link them together. I looks like this:

Tables imported from Excel

```
brand (nvarchar(20) name)
models (nvarchar(20) parent, nvarchar(50 name))
```

Tables after my amends

```
brand (int ident id, nvarchar(20) name, tinyint status)
models (int ident id, int parent_id,
                  nvarchar(20) parent, nvarchar(50) name, tinyint status)
```

As you can see I'd like to link table models using parent_id to table brand using id.

Select is ok, I have done that.

What I need is create bulk update which would put brand id into model parent_id.

Conditions are:

```
set models.parent_id = brand.id where brand.name = model.parent
```

I hope it is clear. Basically I want to change linking field `model.parent` to `model.parent_id`. There is a possibility that brand.name can change and if that happens table models would be unable to link to correct parent.

And I want to do that in bulk, to go through all the records in brand and update all relevant records in models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE
   m
SET
  parent_id = b.id
FROM
   models m
   JOIN
   brand b ON b.name = m.parent
```

I'd them assume you want to remove models.parent

```
 ALTER TABLE models DROP COLUMN parent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE models
SET parent_id = brand.id
FROM brand
WHERE brand.name = models.parent
```